# Is the "rope-based fashion" a fictional element?

Tags: 3-percent

On the show [3%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3%25), we see various characters wear clothes that seem to be adorned with a network of ropes. *I noticed this only during the last couple of episodes, but it may have been around for a longer time within the series.*

Some examples are visible in [the final sequence of the series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CurZjtBJna8). In the linked video, this is visible on the recurring character at 1:59, and on Elisa during the last few shots before the screen fades to black. Interestingly, the same design element seemed to be a part of the military uniform that André Santana wears during his last scenes - although in his case, the network is made of some sort of black straps rather than ropes.

**Is this a real-world fashion trend (maybe in Brazil, where that series originates) that was incorporated into the series, or is this meant to be a futuristic detail of the fictional world presented on the show?**

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image: the back side of André Santana's military uniform]

Comment: Cable-knit is pretty common around the world.

Comment: @Valorum: Ok ... but the style I'm referring to is quite different from that, I'd say.

Comment: This looks like that pervy Japanese sex rope play; shibari

Comment: I think there's also a flash of rope fashion in the movie version of the Lathe of Heaven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Rope Fashion]

It does show up from time to time in [fashion shows](https://www.dezeen.com/2013/03/09/autumn-winter-2013-collection-by-eilish-macintosh/).

If you've got ~$130 burning a hole in your pocket, J Crew will happily sell you [rope sandals](https://www.jcrew.com/us/p/womens_category/shoes/sandals/rope-laceup-flat-sandals/AP724?color_name=natural&sale=true&noPopUp=true&srccode=Paid_Search%7CSmart_Shopping%7CGoogle%7CSS_ACQ_WPROD_SHOESxxxxxxxx_EVG_ROAS_XXX_COUSA_EN_EN_A_CREW_GO_SH_SSC_xxxxxxxxxx,shop_wshoes_x_xxx,PRODUCT_GROUP,71700000070515154,58700006214276318,p57821975810&utm_source=Google&utm_medium=Paid_Search&utm_campaign=SS_ACQ_WPROD_SHOESxxxxxxxx_EVG_ROAS_XXX_COUSA_EN_EN_A_CREW_GO_SH_SSC_xxxxxxxxxx,shop_wshoes_x_xxx&utm_content=Shopping&NoPopUp=True&gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=Cj0KCQjw59n8BRD2ARIsAAmgPmLURDhajGMFQeK2qZSvfGocWCfr1Q7FglOfZJE8MjEhA6Iuapl7uAsaAso1EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) for designer prices.

[image]

I've also seen hand-made rope sandals turn up at Renaissance Festivals and some "earth markets."  It either 1) Matches the buyer's period correct attire OR 2) Reuses materials, which allows buyers to virtue signal by fashion.

I think the 3% used it to highlight the extreme poverty on the mainland.  It's both eye-catching, and immediately makes the viewer wonder the depth of poverty that wearing rope has become a fashion statement.